# What do the letter suffixes on SVN version numbers mean?

Tags: svn

We have a svnversion reported as 22625P.

What does the "P" mean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try `svnversion --help`

```
4123:4168     mixed revision working copy
4168M         modified working copy
4123S         switched working copy
4123P         partial working copy, from a sparse checkout
4123:4168MS   mixed revision, modified, switched working copy
```

Answer (score 3):

It's also possible you haven't done any sparse checkouts, and "P" means "punched up". The working copy has been subjected to too many SVN version upgrades, or whatever cleanup can't repair. Probably best to check out a new working copy.

PS: this sort of thing happened with versions of SVN around that time; it hasn't happened anywhere I saw in the year 2010 or later, and I use a lot of SVN features a lot of the time.